# Run garbage collector in RAD

Tags: garbage-collection, rad

In RAD, is there a way to forcibly run garbage collector on the jvm that is running the RAD itself? If not, can I run a java program that will connect to the RAD jvm and trigger its garbage collector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaushik,

Eclipse has for a while now allowed to view the Heap Status of the JVM that it is running on. It is available on all products built on top of it.

Go to Prefernces -> General and check Show Heap Status.

To the lower right of the screen you should find the heap info and then a trash can.

You can click on the trash can to request eclipse/RAD to run a GC. I believe this is what you are looking for!

HTH

Manglu